# Email notification when using PayPal Payout API

Tags: email, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to deal with Payouts API and I have some questions.

I'm using developer account and have 2 "fake" accounts in it, one as a seller and another one as a buyer.

When I'm sending payout request with email of buyer-user from my sandbox then user's balance debited directly without any prompt or notification to his email. Then I tried to send request with email which is not from my sandbox (actually it was my real email) and again I haven't got email with prompt or notification. Also this payment was rejected.

**How I can test notification features?**

I want to make payout call so the recipient should receive email notification before he get the money onto account. Also I want PayPal send email notification to user who don't have PayPal account when I'm sending the money.

Comment: did you got any solution..?

Comment: Actually I didn't.
I've tested this flow with real money and real 'production' environment.
I can describe flow if you need it, but paypal behaviour is mostly as described in documentation.

Comment: any solution for sandbox?